What would happen if someone set up fake polling stations?
This is based on an Onion community post I saw a few days ago, with the headline of (paraphrased) "Person with 'I Vorted' badge believes polling station might not have been real after all".
Now, it's rather obvious this is not something that's actually happening, but I am curious about what the legal consequences of this would be (which I guess probably differ per state). I guess it'd lead to criminal prosecution for voting fraud, but what would happen with the votes which had been cast there?

Some states are having kids design their "I Voted" stickers, so it might very well be real!

One can also fake a police station, a post office or a church or a hospital - historical examples pretty much do exist. Of course, nothing that happens inside is related to the real thing, e.g. votes will not be counted in the ellection.

For the purpose of this question, can you please clarify: would the fake polling station be clearly indicated as fake, or would people be misled to believe it were a real polling station?

@gerrit Misled, though I wouldn't mind answers for clearly indicated ones either.

It would be a crime in almost every state, although the exact state law would vary, of course. See, e.g., Colorado Revised Statutes § 1-13-109 (false statements) while really intended initially as a defamation/misrepresentation about an issue type statute, it would also apply to statements misleading people about whether they have cast a valid ballot. See also C.R.S. § 1-13-112 (offenses related to mail ballots:) "Any person who, by use of force or other means, unduly influences an elector to vote in any particular manner or to refrain from voting . . . upon conviction shall be punished as provided in section 1-13-111." And C.R.S. § 1-13-706 (delivering/receiving a ballot when not an official).
In Colorado, the exact mechanism of the fraud would influence which offense applies, because there is not just a general law prohibiting election related fraud. Only specific acts that result in election fraud are prohibited. Some other jurisdictions, in contrast, have a "catchall" prohibition against election fraud that has the advantage of covering novel kinds of election fraud that nobody has thought of or attempted before.
The votes cast there would not be counted, because it's a fake polling station, and that's pretty much the definition of a fake polling station.
Of course, if the polling station is clearly indicated as fake, this is not fraud or a crime, and is instead "pretend play", as might be the case on a movie set, or in an elementary school where a teacher is teaching students about elections. No one would be mistaken in thinking that they had really voted after having gone to a pretend polling station of this kind.

For it being a crime, do you have any good references as to what sort of crime it'd fall under, legally speaking? I'm assuming election fraud?

Colorado Revised Statutes § 1-13-109 (false statements) while really intended initially as a defamation/misrepresentation about an issue type statute, it would also apply to statements misleading people about whether they have cast a valid ballot. See also C.R.S. § 1-13-112 (offenses related to mail ballots:) "Any person who, by use of force or other means, unduly influences an elector to vote in any particular manner or to refrain from voting . . . upon conviction shall be punished as provided in section 1-13-111." And C.R.S. § 1-13-706 (delivering/receiving a ballot when not an official).

The exact mechanism of the fraud would influence which offense applies.

Isn't the exact mechanism of the fraud to trick people into thinking they voted at a real polling station so that they won't vote at a real one?

@vsz But, do they use fake ballots or accept real mail ballots that were mailed to someone in advance? What exactly was said? What did they do to make it look real? Did the people running it hold any governmental office? Etc.

You ask: what would happen with the votes which had been cast there?
There would have been no "votes" cast at a fake polling station. Nothing that is done at a fake polling station could constitute a vote for the purpose of election law.
For just one example of a state defining a vote to be from official ballots, see Nebraska R.S. 32-914

Official ballots shall be used at all elections...

And 32-916:

Two judges of election or a precinct inspector and a judge of election shall affix their initials to the official ballots. The judge of election shall deliver a ballot to each registered voter after complying with section 32-914.

The law therefore does not specify what would happen with any pieces of paper used at the fake polling station. They would presumably be collected as evidence of a crime (presumably 18 USC §241, or any one of a number of state offences, like Nebraska's 32-1521 which makes it a misdemeanor to print a fake official ballot), but that is within the discretion of the investigators.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
